# Redundant thank you notes in questions

Tags: discussion

Would it be wise to consider such posts as a subject for "auto" edit or add to the faq?

It seems redundant to ask for review or little personal notes on the site which purpose is to review the code by community. It's like starting with "Please answer" in the title on another StackExchange site.

It's annoying (in my opinion) because it doesn't add anything relevant to the question. Stuff like:

- "Thanks in advance"
- "I appreciate your response"
- "Thank you for your time"
- etc.

I understand it would be appropriate to thank someone after they help you and review your code. But that could be done with a more personal and direct note instead of in the actual question.

Comment: This has been implemented on many other SE sites.

Comment: It has? Do you know why we don't have it on CR as well?